# auto increment variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables

How can I auto-increment a variable so each time it is used, it is incremented by one, starting with 0?

For example:

```
i = i+1 || 0 

arr[i] = "foo"
arr[i] = "bar"
arr[i] = "foobar"

arr #=> ["foo","bar","foobar"]
```

I'm getting a `NoMethodError` **undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: Is your intent to actually use `i` as an array index for assignment as in your example? If it is, why not just use the `<<` array append operator to fill the array?

Comment: Don't write code like `i = i+1 || 0`. It's not idiomatic, nor is it particularly readable or maintainable. Instead do the normal thing and assign `i = 0`, then use `i += 1` wherever you need it to increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable is just a name. It doesn't have behavior. If you want behavior, use a method:

```
def i
  @i ||= -1
  @i += 1
end

arr = []

arr[i] = 'foo'
arr[i] = 'bar'
arr[i] = 'foobar'

arr #=> ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
```

Alternatively:

```
_i = -1

define_method(:i) do
  _i += 1
end

arr = []

arr[i] = 'foo'
arr[i] = 'bar'
arr[i] = 'foobar'

arr #=> ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
```

But really, what you have is just a very convoluted way of saying

```
arr = %w[foo bar foobar]
```

which is much clearer.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think `define_method` is available unless you are calling it on a class or module.  I just tried it out here in IRB.  Also, if it does work it would affect the object you called it on.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no way to associate variables with behaviors — in fact, doing anything with local variables besides just reading and setting them in the obvious way is nigh impossible in standard Ruby — and integers cannot change value.

However, if  you are really looking to do something like this with an arrays, you can just use the `<<` operator to push to the end of the array:

```
arr = []
arr << "foo"
arr << "bar"
arr << "foobar"

arr #=> ["foo","bar","foobar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are pretty good.  I would just like to add a few ways that I would implement it.

You could use a Proc:

```
i = -1
next_i = Proc.new { i += 1 }
next_i.call  # => 0
next_i.call  # => 1
```

You could use an Enumerator:

```
ids = Enumerator.new { |y| i = -1; loop { y << (i+=1) } }
ids.next     # => 0
ids.next     # => 1
```

If it makes sense in your application for the ids to come from some larger object, you could define a method in that object like this:

```
def next_id
  @i ||= -1
  @i += 1
end
```

Comment: Enumerator solution, quite elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like what you're *trying* to do, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
ary = []
i = -1
ary[i += 1] = 'foo'
ary[i += 1] = 'bar'
ary # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Instead, do the idiomatic and expected thing and assign to an array one of these ways:

```
ary = ['foo', 'bar']
ary = %w[foo bar]
ary # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Or, use the `<<` operator to append on the fly, as the other answers recommend.